How can I tangle tagged blocks to a file?
I have my configuration in org-mode and I want to debug with a custom el file.
I want to tag the most basic blocks in my org file, to make a simple el file that I can start Emacs with.
Is this the proper way to do it and how can I do it?;)

Tags decorate headlines, so it depends on whether there is a one-one correspondence in your file between headlines and blocks: if you have three blocks under one headline and you want to tangle just one of them, then tags alone will not work.

You mean org-mode tags? I don't necessarily have to use org-mode tags. I was thinking more of a way to tag a source code block, if that's possible, or some other way to say that a certain source code block is to be included in a tangle to a specific file.

Yes, I was talking about Org mode tags. User-defined tags you will have to implement on your own. However, you can use the :tangle header with a specific file on all the blocks that you want to tangle and let the others be tangled to the default location (or vice versa, depending on which set is the more numerous). That can be considered a kind of tagging, but the mechanism already exists.

I have the entire Emacs configuration in org-mode that generates my init.el, but if I want to create an init.debug.el, which just contains parts of the config, then how should I do that? I don't want to duplicate source code blocks. Some blocks, like setting the garbage collector, etc. is the same for both init files.

Can you reorganize the file so that the blocks that are necessary for both the normal init and the debug init are in one area and all the other blocks (the ones that are only needed in the normal init) are in another? Perhaps under different top-level headlines?
